# Namespace aliases in Oxygene

Tags: .net, oxygene

Is there a way to use namespace aliases in Oxygene .net?

ie:
Whats the Oxygene equivalent of the C# code
 `using someOtherName =  System.Timers.Timer;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is possible, just define it like you would define a type.
For example:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication37;

interface

type
  ConsoleApp = class
  public
    class method Main(args: array of String);
  end;

  someOtherName = System.Timers.Timer;

implementation

class method ConsoleApp.Main(args: array of String);
begin
  var t1 := new someOtherName;
end;

end.
```